# React Material-UI labelDisplayedRows on TablePagination

Tags: material-ui

I have this component for TablePagination:

```
<TablePagination
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50]}
    component="div"
    count={rows.length}
    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
    page={page}
    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
    style={{width:'10px'}}
    labelRowsPerPage={'Filas por página'}
    labelDisplayedRows={ (from, to, count=rows.length) => (`${from}-${to === -1 ? count : to} de ${count}`)
    }
/>
```

According to https://material-ui.com/es/api/table-pagination/

`labelDisplayedRows` is a `func`  but I don't understand where are defined those vars `from`, and `to`

I get: `[object Object]-undefined de 11` in the render

Answer (score 2):

worked for me:

```
labelDisplayedRows={(page) =>
              `${page.from}-${page.to === -1 ? page.count : page.to} از ${
                page.count
              }`
            }
```

also you can use components here, like this:

```
function defaultLabelDisplayedRows({ from }) {
    return (<div>{from}</div>)
  }
```

and then in your pagination component it should be:

```
labelDisplayedRows={(page) => defaultLabelDisplayedRows(page)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it from:

```
labelDisplayedRows={ (from=page) => (`${from.from}-${from.to === -1 ? from.count : from.to} de ${from.count}`})
```

Answer (score 0):

@pmiranda it works perfect but there is an error with some curly brace and parenthesis.

It should be:

labelDisplayedRows={(from = page) => `${from.from}-${from.to === -1 ? from.count : from.to} de ${from.count}`}

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
const defaultLabelDisplayedRows: React.FC<LabelDisplayedRowsArgs> = (props): React.ReactElement<any, any> => {
  return(
    <>
      <p>
        <b> Mostrando itens {" "}
          <span style={{color:"#FFB03A"}}>
            { props.from > 0 && props.from < 10 ? `0${props.from}-0${props.to}` : `${props.from}-${props.to}`}
          </span>
        </b>   
        <p style={{padding: 0, margin: 0}}>total de {props.count} itens</p> 
      </p>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
      <TablePagination 
        count={props.count}
        page={props.page}
        rowsPerPage={props.rowsPerPage}
        labelDisplayedRows={ ({ from, to, count, page }) => { 
          return defaultLabelDisplayedRows({from, to, count, page}) 
        }}
```

results

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Pagination: (props) => (
    <TablePagination
    {...props}        
    labelDisplayedRows={({from, to, count}) => <>{`${from}-${to} ${t('dataGrid:rowsOf')} ${count}`}</>}
    />
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?